# React JS - hide a text of the parent component by clicking on the NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this parent Component that simply renders a 'p' of the introduction text and a child component called 'PortfolioMenu'

```
import React from 'react'
import PortfolioMenu from './PortfolioMenu'

const Portfolio = () => {
  return (
  <div className="wrapper2">     
    <p>
      Here is an Introduction text 
    </p> 
  <PortfolioMenu/>
  </div>   
 )
}
export default Portfolio
```

Now in the child component 'PortfolioMenu', when I click on some link of NavLink I would like to make the 'p' of the parent component 'Portfolio' disappear.  How can I solve it? Thank you

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import Houses from './Houses'
import Interiors from './Interiors'   

const PortfolioMenu = () => {

return (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <div class="wrapper2">
        <div className="wrapper-portfolio">
          <Route exact path='/portfolio/houses' render={() => <Houses />} />
          <Route exact path='/portfolio/interiors' render={() =><Interiors/>}  
          />          
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul className="portfolio-menu">
          <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact 
           to="/portfolio/houses">Houses</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact 
          to="/portfolio/interiors">interiors</NavLink></li>             
         </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </Router>
   </div>
 )
}
export default PortfolioMenu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```html
import React from 'react'
import PortfolioMenu from './PortfolioMenu'

const Portfolio = () => {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props){
      this.state = {
        visibleP: true
      };
    }
    
    this.handleMenuClick = this.handleMenuClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleMenuClick() {
    this.setState({
      visibleP: false
    });
  }

  return (
  <div className="wrapper2"> 
    {
      this.visibleP &&
      <p>
        Here is an Introduction text 
      </p> 
    }
  <PortfolioMenu onHandleMenuClick={this.handleMenuClick}/>
  </div>   
 )
}


import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import Houses from './Houses'
import Interiors from './Interiors'   

const PortfolioMenu = () => {

return (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <div class="wrapper2">
        <div className="wrapper-portfolio">
          <Route exact path='/portfolio/houses' render={() => <Houses />} />
          <Route exact path='/portfolio/interiors' render={() =><Interiors/>}  
          />          
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul className="portfolio-menu">
          <li>
            <NavLink
              activeClassName="active"
              exact 
              to="/portfolio/casas"
              onClick={this.props.onHandleMenuClick()}
            >
              casas
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink
              activeClassName="active"
              exact 
              to="/portfolio/interiores"
              onClick={this.props.onHandleMenuClick()}
            >
              interiores
            </NavLink>
          </li>             
         </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </Router>
   </div>
 )
}

PortfolioMenu.propTypes = {
  onHandleMenuClick: PropTypes.func
};

export default PortfolioMenu;
```

You can't have a dump component. Here you need to pass props from child component to parent component.

Comment: Thank you I will test your solution.

Comment: I tested your solution. I did the recomended steps by you but it caused an error Message:

**Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

Comment: **This error message is relationed about the lines:**
`this.state = {  visibleP: true  }`
**And:**
`<li><NavLink onClick={props.handleMenuClick()}activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/interiores">interiores</NavLink></li>`